# Show Progress Dialog while Processing OnActivityResult

Tags: java, android

I have written below codes where when user click attach button to select photos.

Below is code for same.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();

                    intent.setType("*/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select file to upload "), 1);
```

Below is code for OnActivityResult

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


        if (requestCode == 1) {



            if (null != data) { // checking empty selection
                if (null != data.getClipData()) { // checking multiple selection or not
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.getClipData().getItemCount(); i++) {
                        Uri uri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                        Log.i(TAG, "Path" + getPath(uri));
                        filespath.add(getPath(uri));

                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getPath(uri), options);
                        bitmaps.add(bitmap);
                    }
                } else {
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Now user can select multiple photos and I realized that when photos are more than 10, I get warning too much work done on main thread. when user click on Done button after selecting photos, I have Recycler view where I am showing thumbnail of images selected by user before final upload.

Now issue is when user click Done and till it shows Thumbnail, how can I show ProgressDialog , handle freeze screen and avoid warning work done on main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the parsing and loading work off the main thread you can just wrap everything in an AsyncTask. Given the small amount of code shown, I don't know what functions do what in the above, so this might have to be adjusted a bit. Move all the parsing logic, etc to do in the background as such:

```
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Bitmap>>() {
        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute()
        {
            //show progress dialog
            //Are you trying to prevent the user from clicking on the UI while updating?
            //You can do something such as:
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Bitmap> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //perform the logic, this will return a list of all the Bitmaps to onPostExecute
            //Do NOT perform any ui logic here.
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Bitmap> bitmaps) {
            //cancel progress dialog.
            //Update the UI with the response.
            //Clear the window lock:
            getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        }
    };
```

Comment: u means I cal Async in OnActivityResult and do all there. Actually I tried to do this using Thread. I think this can be achieved. thanks

Comment: Using a thread would work too, it's just AsyncTask makes stuff like this cleaner. When you run the task make sure to call *just* execute(). Do not call the get() after it, it will block your UI thread. As for where to put it, ultimately it's wherever works best and is cleanest for you.

Comment: It is still issue with too much work on Main thread. actually the time is taken between when user Click Done button after selecting photos and app resume the activity. Can this task be done on Async or Thread.

Comment: So you're saying the above code is *not* where the issue is occurring? You can wrap a lot of things in a thread or a task.... without knowing the code, it's hard to say. You can try it and see if you achieve the desired result.

Comment: precisely, I want to attach files like we do in WhatsApp as there I found no lagging and thumbnail screen come immediately after user click done button. I m looking for same smoothness.

Comment: Gotchya. I'd try finding exactly what is so causing so much lag, and move it to the background, and it might be worth running the Android Profiler, to try to see what is happening exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180674/discussion-between-panache-and-sbso).